# Writing Images to ImageIcon in loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, swing, imageicon

```
    public class generateTypes {

       public ImageIcon[] natureTypes = new ImageIcon[5];
       public ImageIcon returnType = null;

        public ImageIcon generateTypes(int random) {

            for(int i = 0; i <= natureTypes.length; i++) {

                ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(generateTypes.class.getResource("resources/types/type" + i + ".png"));
                natureTypes[i] = image;

            }

            returnType = natureTypes[1];
            return returnType;
        }
    }
```

As you can see when I try write images to an ImageIcon array from resource folder, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

What I am doing wrong? And How can I solve this?

[Project folder;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yByn9.png)

Comment: 1. Make sure the image resources are actually available (always start by unzipping the jar file just to be sure). 2. Consider using an absolute path instead of a relative one (ie `/resources/...` instead of `resources/...`)

Comment: Ah, thank you for your answer. I saw the problem when I check the resource folder. Problem is "<=" in the for loop. Because I don't have 5th image.

Comment: Ah, yes, that would be unhelpful :P